# How to correctly markup the signature of an HTML5 website creator?

Tags: html

I ask myself the question of how best to mark my signature (which I usually place in the footer) when I create a website.

For example :

```
<a href="#goToWebisteCreator">Website created by xxx</a>
```

Here it's just a link, and I would have liked to know if there was a way to specify that.

I wanted to use the attribute `rel="author"` but it seems bad to me.

Thank you for your reactions!

Comment: There is no real way to do that. Just make it a link to your website. The `author` is for, lets say a blog post.

Comment: You could use a title attribute, which shows on hover: `<a href="yourwebsite" title="HTML5 site authored by ME">Website created by xxx</a>` but it's obviously not an official HTML5 element.